# How to manage Gmail Vacation-Responder settings programmatically?

Tags: android, cordova, gmail, google-apps

I'm developing a Gmail client application using Phonegap for a company that uses Gmail as their corporate mail.

The application must allow users of this domain to access Vacation Responder settings and update them. For this purpose I'm using the [Google Apps Email Settings API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_vacation-responder_settings), but I've had no success. 
It works only if I login to the API with the admin credentials. In this case the following  request succeeds:

```
GET https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{domain name}/{username}/vacation
```

If I login as a non-admin user and make the same request, Google responds with error 403 "Domain cannot use API"

Is there any way or any API to programmatically manage email settings for the non-admin users by own, without admin?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Only the admin account can make changes to the email settings API for users. Users cannot use the Email Settings API directly. I recommend that your app make use of a user account created as a service account with super admin priveledges.